# Scaling with Core Animation

Tags: cocoa, core-animation

I have a NSScrollView that I want to scale down 50%. I do this with the below code:

```
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];

animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.00];
animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.50];
[animation setDuration:0.20f];

[animation setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];
[animation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];

[self.scrollView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"drag"];
```

This works, but the scroll view's document view receives mousedown events when I click outside of the scaled down view. So although the scroll view and its content visually looks scaled down, they technically aren't.

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Layer animation acts exactly as you describe (The animations only change the appearance, not the underlying geometry.)

Try using UIView block animation and change the scroll view's transform rather than the layer's.

EDIT:

Oh. Sorry, I thought this was iOS. I guess I should have noticed that you said it was an NSView, not a UIView. I do most of my work in iOS these days, and my OSX experience is mostly from before the days of Core Animation.

I think the answer is to get the view's animation proxy and set the change on that, but I've only done a few learning exercises with animation proxies in Mac OS, so I'd have to do some digging to look up the specifics.

Comment: Thanks Duncan. Forgot to mention that it's an OS X app. But I guess the same applies?

Comment: Just a note: Setting the `additive` property to `YES` changes the geometry (model layer) too when animating with CoreAnimation

Comment: @adamWaite, wouldn't setting th additive property change the model LAYER, but not the properties of the view?

Comment: Unsure to be totally honest. I'm pretty new to CoreAnimation and haven't used it so much. I think you're right though. I tried animating with a scale transform earlier today and the pixels rendered on the screen but weren't responding to touch suggesting a CGRectZero frame. I scrapped it in favour of modifying the view :/.